# Web development burnout

Tags: careers

I want to get out of web development and my current job.  The company has a culture of learning the latest bleeding edge framework for each new project and it is very tiring keeping on track of everything.

We are a very small team.  I have spoken to my boss about this and he ensures that I am to work my set hours.  The boss is clearly very smart and he is personable.  I'm probably what you consider an average/pretty good developer - not rockstar but hardworking and with a sound enough computer science background.

But there is a ridiculous amount of things to learn.  I'm just not into it anymore.

My question is: how can I scope out companies that avoid this, and find a good fit for me?

I'm well aware there is no such thing as the perfect job, but I like to think I can influence things to make myself happier.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think your question #1 is sound, but #2 on it's own would get your question closed, since we don't give personal advice on whether something is worth it, that is a very personal decision everybody has to make on their own. If you can focus on #1, I think it's a good question for this site.

Comment: There is plenty of web companies out there with a stable stack. For bigger companies you can search what kind of technology they are using, for smaller companies you can derive it from their job ads and you can ask.

Comment: Ok, I can see how it is personal.  I'll edit to ask only my first question,

Comment: I would think most companies avoid the bleeding edge until after it stops bleeding if not further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask them during the job interview? For instance:

> How often do you switch web frameworks?

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, companies you may be interested in are large established enterprises

I found that in these companies at any moment there are several technology levels being utilized and you can stay at one stack for several years, especially on internal projects

The other type are smaller companies, but these are greater risk of them going under

Answer (score 3):

> how can I scope out companies that avoid this, and find a good fit for
>   me?

Ask them in the interview stage. You can also normally see this because companies using older tech will normally state that as a requirement in the job description. So look out for companies using older tech and ask them.

As a note this will be partially career limiting depending on how old the web tech is. If someone is using a really old technology from say 15 years ago and is not willing to change you'll need to put that on your resume. So when you apply for a new company they see you've only worked with that old tech for the last however long.

Also as tiring as learning new web technologies is using old technologies can also be just as frustrating. From bugs that aren't fixed for years to poor non-exsistent documentation you'll find just as much frustration.

It might be easier to just deal with your source of frustration that you have at the moment rather than move company. That could be in the form of telling the company that you work with that they shouldn't be switching tech so much or learning to deal with the switch of tech. At the very least dealing with the frustration that this is causing you.

Comment: I've been in dialogue with senior staff.  I see what you're saying about legacy code and that is obviously the other extreme.  This is something I'll need to gauge in the interview process.  I'm sure there must be smart companies that balance between the two.

Comment: It's not always about changing the process but sometimes changing ourselves. You're not going to be able to change a company but you can try to make small changes here or there to make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're looking for from the way you've worded your question.

You state:

> I want to get out of web development and my current job.

Which is it? It may very well be both- you want to get out of web development **and** your current job. But it might be that you just want out of your current job.

Assuming that your current job title is something like 'Web Developer'... web technology is constantly changing- the drive across most industries for being able to do more, more independently/ remotely is constantly growing (especially now, with many people around the world being required to work from home due to the coronavirus pandemic). I would expect that in this line of work, you are going to be expected to be able to jump on board with new technologies/ tools as and when required (either by your company, as they choose to use a particular technology or tool, or by the industry, as newer technologies become standard and exisiting technologies evolve).

Do you want to stay in web development? If so, why? If not, why not?
Are there particular technologies/ tools you enjoy using? If so, you could perhaps look for roles that specifically require those skills or similar skills? But keep in mind that even those tools and technologies will change over the years.

If you want to get out of web development, work out what it is you want to do instead, and then pursue getting experience in that.

It does sound like your company is keen to keep growing the knowledge base of its employees (which is not in and of itself a bad thing- though granted, changing technologies just for the sake of it is not the best practice). If they are willing to spend the time and money training you in the new technologies they require you to use- you get to expand your knowledge base and skillset- definitely a positive, and something you can use to promote yourself when applying for other jobs in the future.

If you want to stay in web development, but don't want to be constantly learning new technologies, maybe look at bigger companies with large web development projects- as larger projects are less likely to 'change with the wind' due to the vast cost that would be associated with it.

For example- I work for a large company, who are involved with a number of public sector projects, and recently joined a team working on a project which is about to undergo a full tech-refresh, due to the existing technology stack being about to become unsupported. The 'new' technology that they are going to use to re-write the web solution is WPF...

Comment: These are all very valid points and ideas.  It is a personal decision which I'm trying to decide what is best for me.

Comment: All the best with making your decision! I know from personal experience what it's like getting that 'burnout' (for want of a better word) as a developer. Personally- as some of my jobs as a developer had involved taking on the roles and responsibilities of a BA- I found I actually enjoyed that side of things a lot more than the development side- which I had been adament I wanted to get into since I was a teen... My current role (the one I aluded to in my answer) is actually a BA role- and making the move away from development into the BA side of things was definitely the right move for me.